# ASPNETBoilerplate - Custom Claim auto expire after sometime authentication generated claim available

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, .net-7.0

I'm using the `.NET 7.0` Ready `aspnetboilerplate` Framework.

While login the user I've added a few Claims. but the concern are custom added Claim auto-removed after some time.

Can anyone know the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have cookie authentication set? The problem is most likely an expired cookie. Since the custom claims are not added to the user claims in the database, they are lost on refresh because the claims are not added in the method called. You can add claims in the following ways:

```
userManager.AddClaim(xxx);
```

If you don't want to save the claims in the database, there is another method in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39897172/custom-claims-lost-on-identity-re-validation) that might help you.

Comment: True if we go with this Claim added in the database. I'll appreciate your effort thank you.

Comment: Hi @jishan siddique, if my answer helped you, could you please accept it as answer?